# What's the translation of “hero image" in French?

Tags: traduction

A hero image [is](https://www.optimizely.com/optimization-glossary/hero-image/) ([mirror](https://archive.ph/xf0Z8)):

> a website design term used to describe an oversized banner image at the top of a website.
>
> [image]

What's the translation of “hero image" in French?

I unsuccessfully tried [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=fr&text=Hero%20image%0Abut&op=translate) and  [linguee](https://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=Hero+image).

Answer (score 5):

Une bannière (plus rarement : un bandeau) est une image allongée qui occupe une bonne partie de la page pour une bannière horizontale, ou de l'écran pour une bannière verticale.

Sans plus de précision, *la bannière* d'un site ou d'une page peut désigner celle horizontale en haut de page, notamment si c'est la plus grande ou la seule présente.
Sinon, on pourra parler comme proposé en commentaires de *bannière principale* ou de *bannière d'en-tête*.

Comment: Thanks , "image placée en haut d'une page web" -> bannière isn't necessarily based on top. Many bannières are at the bottom, vertical on the side, and sometimes somewhere in the middle. So we'd have to specify "bannière en haut de page".

Comment: or ***Bannière principale***.

Comment: @jlliagre good idea!

Comment: To stress that the banner is on top, most natural to me would be "bannière d'en-tête", especially in a Web or document context ("en-tête" meaning "header").

Answer (score 1):

On pourrait utiliser en contexte [*image de premier plan*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26543635) pour l'« image ou série d'images surdimensionnées occupant la partie supérieure et toute la largeur d'une page Web [...] » (GDT), tout en se démarquant du domaine de la publicité.

Comment: Sur un ton plus léger on peut imaginer _image héroïne de l'en-tête de page_  ;-)